# CDialog object not created

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, cdialog

I have a problem with an MFC project. The project has recently been converted to an window less project, meaning the window it is still created but it is hidden. It worked fine, no problems.

Now it has a problem, the object created by a class that derives CDialog is not created.

```
class CCRViewerDlg : public CDialog
```

And the problem occures here :

```
CCRViewerDlg dlg; //here hWnd = 0x000000

if( dlg.Create( CCRViewerDlg::IDD )) 
{
    dlg.ShowWindow( SW_HIDE );
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.RunModalLoop();
}
```

The code is not entering the if loop, and hWnd remains unaddressed.

The code above is in the first line's of the `BOOL CCRViewerApp::InitInstance()`

Could you help me identify the cause of this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `dlg.Create()` return `FALSE` or is it just because you set its window to `SW_HIDE`?

Comment: Most of the time dialog creation failure is due to missing corresponding resource or wrong id.

Comment: if `dlg.Create()` fails you can use `GetLastError()` to find out why it's failing (on Windows).

Comment: I have checked with `GetLastError()` and it returned the value 0.So i guess there is no error.

Comment: Try to step through the MFC source code if dlg.Create this will often give you some hints.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had `Custom Control` in CMydlg, but without any initialization/linking through message map.

and when I created dlg I got this error as you:

```
myDlg.Create(IDD_DIALOG_MY, this);     // myDlg.m_hwnd = 0x000000
printf("GetLastErr - %d\n", GetLastError()); // err : 0
```

what I did is:

just removed custom control from dlg for now

in order to create dlg first